# add drawable in relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, drawable

I have Image in my layout and I want when user clicked on image, 4 drawable (corner button) added in corner of the image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there are many ways to that.

Using layoutparams you can set layout params programatically.

like

```
LayoutParams param = new LayoutParam(LayoutPara.width, LayoutParam.height);
//your rules...

imageView.setlayoutParams(param);
```

here you can set margintop, bottom, left and right and alignParentLeft.... so on

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` field to the relative layout in the xml. Use that id in the class to create view dynamically.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.YourID);
imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image);  
//Add View to Layout:    
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
```